# DNU publish --no-source from MSBuild

Tags: .net, msbuild, asp.net-core, dnx, dnu

Is it possible to invoke `dnu publish` with the `--no-source` attribute from MSBuild when triggering the `FileSystemPublish` target?

MSBuild command:

```
/t:Build,FileSystemPublish /p:PublishConfiguration=$(BuildConfiguration) /p:PublishOutputPathNoTrailingSlash=$(build.stagingDirectory)
```

MSBuild ultimately calls the following:

```
dnu publish "C:/MyApplication" --out "C:/a/MyApplication" --configuration Release --runtime dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta6 --quiet
```

I would like to append the `--no-source` attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can pass /p:compileSource=true to set the --no-source option during dnu publish.

(Also, you don't have to use the specific publish target FileSystemPublish, you can set the msbuild property /p:deployOnBuild=true to publish after build.)

Comment: In VS RC2 tooling, this option is no longer available. To publish RC1 dnx based projects (with --no-source option) with rc2 tooling installed you need to follow the instructions from here -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37397315/visual-studio-2015-latest-update-publish-function-does-not-compile-asp-net-cor/37425515