# Visual Studio 2015 (latest update) publish function does not compile ASP.NET Core RC1 sources

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015

I begun working on a new ASP.NET Core RC1 project months ago, and Publishing with Visual Studio 2015, was producing a folder tree ready to deploy without the project C# sources (because it was compiling it in assemblies placed into the folder tree).

Now that I've upgraded the Visual Studio (**only the VS**, **not the project that remains in 1.0.0-*rc1-final***) with latest updates (circa May, 19 2016):
"Microsoft .NET Core 1.0.0 RC2 - VS 2015 Tooling Preview 1", "Microsoft .NET Core 1.0.0 RC2 - SDK Preview 1 (x64)", "Microsoft ASP.NET 5 RC1 Update 1" (1.0.11123.0) and "Microsoft ASP.NET 5 RC1 Update 1" (1.0.20204.0)

it looks that the new Publish functionality of latest VS2015 updates, does not compile anymore the sources, instead it places into the Publish folder tree the project c# sources.

Can someone please indicate me how to force VS Publish functionality to compile again instead copying c# sources into the Publish Folders?

Comment: Facing same issue. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Are you running VS as administrator?

Comment: yes, but nothing changes

Comment: @MarcMart can you create a new publish profile to see if that helps? I'm really confused by this because we actually always produce binaries for RC2 projects. It looks like there is something funny going on here. How did you go from rc1 to rc2, maybe there was something that was not correct in the migration that is causing the problem.

Comment: @SayedIbrahimHashimi no project upgrde have been made, I kept the **RC1**, the "dependencies" are all with 1.0.0-rc1-final. Just upgraded the VS2015

Comment: @SayedIbrahimHashimi I tried to recreate peth publish project but nothing has changed

Answer (score 3):

we removed this option ("Compile source files into NuGet packages") from the Publish dialog in rc2 tooling because this is not applicable for dotnet projects any more.

In order to publish an rc1 project with the –no-source option from VS, you can add this target to the pubxml (target needs to be inside the project and outside the propertygroup).

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
<all your existing property group values>
  </PropertyGroup>

     <Target Name="DnuNoSourcePublish" AfterTargets="GatherAllFilesToPublish" Condition=" '$(CompileSource)' == 'true' ">
        <Exec
          Condition="Exists('$(PublishOutputPath)') and '$(PublishOutputPath)'!='' "
          Command="rmdir /S /Q &quot;$(PublishOutputPath)&quot;"
          WorkingDirectory="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)" />

        <PropertyGroup>
          <DnuCommand>&quot;$(SDKToolingDirectory)\bin\dnu.cmd&quot; publish</DnuCommand>
          <RuntimeArgument Condition=" '$(FinalPublishVersion)' != '' " >--runtime $(FinalPublishVersion)</RuntimeArgument>
          <WwwRootArgument Condition=" '$(WebRoot)' != '' " >--wwwroot $(WebRoot)</WwwRootArgument>
          <WwwRootOutArgument Condition=" '$(WwwRootOut)' != '' " >--wwwroot-out $(WwwRootOut)</WwwRootOutArgument>
          <IISCommandArgument Condition =" '$(IISCommand)' != ''">--iis-command $(IISCommand)</IISCommandArgument>
          <NoSourceArgument Condition=" '$(CompileSource)' == 'true' ">--no-source</NoSourceArgument>
          <NativeArgument Condition="'$(NativeFlag)' == 'true'">--native</NativeArgument>
          <IncludeSymbolsArgument Condition=" '$(IncludeSymbolsFlag)' == 'true'">--include-symbols</IncludeSymbolsArgument>
          <QuietArgument Condition=" '$(QuietFlag)' == 'true'">--quiet</QuietArgument>
        </PropertyGroup>

        <Exec
          Command="SET PATH=$(ExternalToolsPath);@(DnuPublishEnvironmentVariables)
          $(DnuCommand) &quot;$(KPackWorkingDirectory)&quot; --out &quot;$(PublishOutputPathNoTrailingSlash)&quot; --configuration $(PublishConfiguration) $(RuntimeArgument) $(WwwRootArgument) $(WwwRootOutArgument) $(IISCommandArgument) $(NoSourceArgument) $(QuietArgument) $(NativeArgument) $(IncludeSymbolsArgument)"
          WorkingDirectory="$(KPackWorkingDirectory)"/>
      </Target>
</Project>
```

Make sure your property group has this property set

```
 <CompileSource>true</CompileSource>
```

Comment: the .pubxml modified as indicated is not recognized as a runnable publish profile

Comment: Once you modify the publish profile (with the above target added inside the project section), you should be able to invoke publish from the publish dialog and this target will get executed before publishing the contents to the server.

Comment: it works!, my error was replacing the <PropertyGroup> in the .pubxml, everything has to be added... the content of the <Project> tag must be: <PropertyGroup> (mine original, with <CompileSource>true</CompileSource>) and <Target> (exactly as the post)

Answer (score 0):

Looking how VS was publishing prior to the RC2 updates, I noticed the two:

`C:\Users\(user)\.dnx\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-update1\bin\dnu.cmd publish "(destinationFolder)" --out "C:\Users\(user)\AppData\Local\Temp\PublishTemp\(tempFolder)" --configuration Debug --no-source --runtime dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-update1 --wwwroot "wwwroot" --wwwroot-out "wwwroot" --iis-command "web" --quiet`

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" -source:contentPath='C:\Users\(user)\AppData\Local\Temp\PublishTemp\(tempFolder)\' -dest:contentPath='(destinationFolder)' -verb:sync -retryAttempts:2 -disablerule:BackupRule`

so, **deleting the two folders**: `(destinationFolder)` and `C:\Users\(user)\AppData\Local\Temp\PublishTemp\(tempFolder)`, and **running the two commands above** "by hands" in command prompt, I obtained the wanted result